# Php list for specific type

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a school assignment in Php. I've come to a point where I want to store a group of objects (all instances of the same class) in a single object which I then return. At the moment I use arrays for this, but this has a couple of cons for me.

- Arrays do not have and do not support OO-methods
- Arrays do not check or force the type of variable that is added to them

I know that in C# and Java there are specific classes and interfaces for this such as `List`, `Dictionary` and `Map`.

Is there any way to create similar behavior in Php, by writing a class or maybe extending an existing one? (The most important aspect of this is checking/forcing the type of the elements being added)

What i want:

```
$collection = Series::getAll(); // Returns a Collection<Series>, currently returns an array
echo $collection->toJson(); // This is currently not possible, because it's an array

$anotherCollection = new Collection<Movie>(); // I realize Php doesn't support this syntax, but I want this behavior, the syntax can be different for all I care
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Standard PHP Library (SPL)?    http://us2.php.net/spl

Comment: It sounds as if you're looking for something like this... http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While any object will do for typehinting, PHP provides some base classes with array-like capabilities you could extend to suit your needs, such as `ArrayObject` : http://php.net/arrayobject

---

**UPDATE**: usage example

```
class A{}
class B{}

class CustomList extends ArrayObject{
    protected $validType = 'A'; 

    public function offsetSet($index, $val) {
        if(! $val instanceof $this->validType) {
            throw new \Exception('Cannot add item object of class '.get_class($val));
        }
        return parent::offsetSet($index, $val); 
    }
}

$list = new CustomList();
$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$list[] = $a; // this one is ok
$list[] = $b; // fails - throws exception
```

One could set the `validType` property externally (making it public, or using a setter method), or extend the class and override the property in child instances.

Comment: This would mean I would have to write a collection class for every class I write? Which is not what I want, I'm looking for the kind of List l = new List<T>(); behavior, where 1 collection class can be used for multiple objects (by using a different "T" every time)

Comment: Not necesarily, you could extend ArrayObject in a generic CustomList class and define the type-checking constraints you need at the setter level (overriding the default offsetSet method)

Comment: Could you give an example? Also I have updated the question a little.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a big step in the right direction. I'm thinking I will make validType a constructor argument, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way, as you said; by writing a simple class. You'll need to use type-hinting:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Many frameworks / libraries have their own solutions already, it might be worth checking them out:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html
https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/runtime/lib/collection/PropelCollection.php